# Possible values for "Action" value in DOCUSIGN API audit_event

Tags: docusignapi

There is a documentation about possible envelop status value from docusign for a given envelope.

Howver i am trying to understand if there are any documentation which lists out the possible "Action" value from docusign in the "Audit_event" REST API method.

The reaosn is I am storing the audit events locally to avoid multiple API calls and i wanted to account for all the possible action values.

Thanks for reading

Since there were any documentation provided, i am including the staus i have seen based on my reverse engg

```
Registered
Sent Invitations
Printable Copy Delivered
Printable Copy Attached to Email
AccessCode Passed
AccessCode Failed
Viewed
Signed
Approved
Resent
Voided
Declined
Correction Initiated
Correction Cancelled
Viewed In-Session
Corrected
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen any documentation for possible values of the **action** property within a **GET Envelope Audit Events** response -- to the best of my knowledge, none exists.  You might be stuck having to 'reverse engineer' to determine possible values. i.e., create envelopes via the DocuSign web console, act on them in a variety of ways (both as Sender and as Recipient) -- for example: Send Envelope, Void Envelope, Decline Envelope, Sign Envelope, View Envelope, Pass Signer Authentication, Fail Signer Authentication, etc. etc. etc. -- and then examine the corresponding **action** values that appear in the **GET Envelope Audit Events** response for those Envelopes.

Obviously this approach is not ideal, since someone fairly new to DocuSign won't necessarily know all of things that can be done with an Envelope, in order to trigger the various **action** values in the API response.  Perhaps someone from DocuSign will see this post and chime in with a list of all possible values...or better yet, add this info to the API Guide one day soon.

Comment: I am currently in the process of doing it. May be i will update the question with the possible values based on the my analysis for further reference....